# how to publish topics while using messagefilter?

Tags: ros, message-filter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am using an LRF and a servo for my application and need to synchrnize the position of servo and laser data in time. I looked into `message_filter` and trying to play with it. I was wondering whether `ApproximateTime` synchronizer publishes on any topic or if not then how to get the data to publish in user defined topic? I looked into quite a few previously discussed answers on this issue here, but could not understand this part.

I need to access the synchronized dataset for servo and lidar.

thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274790/how-to-publish-topics-while-using-messagefilter?/) by [Spartan_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/21890/spartan_007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2017-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, I got a solution. I initialized publishers on required topics as global variable. Then,  published in the callback of the `registercallback` in the `message_filter`.

---

Originally posted by [Spartan_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/21890/spartan_007/) with karma: 73 on 2017-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0